# Change serialization type on column while preserving data - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization

I have a project that has already launched, and am in the middle of a major refactor, cleaning up all the mistakes my coworker and I have made along the way. In our people table, we decided to store contact info as a serialized hash. However, this has led to the issue that only one unique identifier can be used per record (i.e. if `Person.first.contact_info[:email] = 'test@test.com'......` now this person cannot enter another contact entry and call it 'email').

My question is, is there an easy way to write a migration/rake task to change the column serialization to `Array` while preserving all the data? I was going to add/drop a temp column, but I now realize that I cannot simply change the serialization type in the model *before* I run this, because it won't be read correctly. It seems like a catch 22. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I'd love a one shot migration or task to perform all of this so that a single deploy to the server will effect the change solidly and safely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So......I pieced together a solution. It's rather ugly, but it does the trick. It took some researching, but I got away without using rake. Here is the migration:

```
class ChangeContactInfoSerializationTypeOnPerson < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    # Add temp column and its serialization
    add_column :people, :temp_contact_info, :text
    contents = File.read('app/models/person.rb')
  contents.gsub!(/serialize[\s]*:contact_info,[\s]*Hash/, "serialize :contact_info, Hash \n  serialize :temp_contact_info, Array")
    person_file = File.open('app/models/person.rb', 'w')
    person_file.puts contents
    person_file.close
    # Write data into temp column
    Person.all.each do |p|
      arr_of_hsh = []
      p.contact_info.each do |k,v|
        arr_of_hsh.push({k => v})
      end
      p.update!(temp_contact_info: arr_of_hsh)
    end
    # Remove original column and change serialization
    remove_column :people, :contact_info
    contents.gsub!(/serialize[\s]*:contact_info,[\s]*Hash/, "serialize :contact_info, Array")
    person_file = File.open('app/models/person.rb', 'w')
    person_file.puts contents
    person_file.close
    # Re-add original column and reload the model file
    add_column :people, :contact_info, :text
    Object.send(:remove_const, 'Person')
    load 'person.rb'
    # Copy data back into changed column
    Person.all.each do |p|
      p.update!(contact_info: p.temp_contact_info)
    end
    # Remove temp column and its serialization
    remove_column :people, :temp_contact_info
    contents.gsub!(/[\s]*serialize :temp_contact_info, Array/, '')
    person_file = File.open('app/models/person.rb', 'w')
    person_file.puts contents
    person_file.close
  end

  def down
    # Add temp column and its serialization
    add_column :people, :temp_contact_info, :text
    contents = File.read('app/models/person.rb')
    contents.gsub!(/serialize[\s]*:contact_info,[\s]*Array/, "serialize :contact_info, Array \n  serialize :temp_contact_info, Hash")
    person_file = File.open('app/models/person.rb', 'w')
    person_file.puts contents
     person_file.close
    # Write data into temp column
    Person.all.each do |p|
      hsh = {}
      p.contact_info.each do |i|
        hsh[i.first[0]] = i.first[1] if hsh[i.first[0]].nil?
      end
      p.update!(temp_contact_info: hsh)
    end
    # Remove original column and change serialization
    remove_column :people, :contact_info
    contents.gsub!(/serialize[\s]*:contact_info,[\s]*Array/, "serialize :contact_info, Hash")
    person_file = File.open('app/models/person.rb', 'w')
    person_file.puts contents
    person_file.close
    # Re-add original column and reload the model file
    add_column :people, :contact_info, :text
    Object.send(:remove_const, 'Person')
    load 'person.rb'
    # Copy data back into changed column
    Person.all.each do |p|
      p.update!(contact_info: p.temp_contact_info)
    end
    # Remove temp column and its serialization
    remove_column :people, :temp_contact_info
    contents.gsub!(/[\s]*serialize :temp_contact_info, Hash/, '')
    person_file = File.open('app/models/person.rb', 'w')
    person_file.puts contents
    person_file.close
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

It'd be cleaner to copy the column, nullify it, and then load the raw YAML manually as explained in [this post](http://blog.quarternotecoda.com/blog/2011/03/03/migrating-serialized-columns-in-rails/)